# What is the meaning of the default build qualities provided by TFS?

Tags: tfs, default

There is this set of default build qualities:

- Initial Test Passed
- Lab Test Passed
- Ready for Deployment
- Ready for Initial Test
- Rejected
- Released
- UAT Passed
- Under Investigation

I'm not really sure about the meaning of each entry. I lack experience in this area (and additionally, i'm not a native speaker). Is there an explanation of these values somewhere? I'm also interested in related ressources, please feel free to add links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the default build qualities provided with TFS.  They probably won't mean anything to you unless your organization's release process includes steps that would correspond to those qualities.

Resources that might help:

- [How to: Set Build Quality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181734(VS.80).aspx)
- [How to: Create Build Quality States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181735(VS.80).aspx)
- [Understanding the Team Foundation Build Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181730(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Oh, that's mean: MSDN shows a short description of each tag for VS2005 but not for 2008.

Comment: Yes, but the descriptions are redundant, e.g. "Ready for Deployment" is described as "The build is ready for deployment." -- is that deployment to the lab environment, deployment to production?

Answer (score 2):

These are just strings in the build system, so feel free to remove them and add new ones that mean something more useful to your team.

As [Ryan says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685940/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-default-build-qualities-provided-by-tfs/686197#686197), there are some short descriptions given for the default values at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181734(VS.80).aspx